# Auto completion using sqlite in ipad app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sql, ios, sqlite

I wanted auto completion feature in ipad app. I have a sqlite database of words. On typing letters in a search box i load the keywords in a UItableview. I have used the following select query,

```
SELECT word from tbl_words where words like a%
```

When i had few hundred words, every thing worked fine. But when my database grown to have thousands of words, the response is slow. So i made auto completion active only after typing 3 letters. Which gave few number of words yet it is slow.

I looked into sqlite optimization techniques in this [SQLite_optimization_FAQ](http://web.utk.edu/~jplyon/sqlite/SQLite_optimization_FAQ.html). It suggests to avoid like % to make use of indexing.

I know that i can create index for column using

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_words ON mytest(words);
```

Is there anything else i can do to improve performance?. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of hitting the database everytime, load the all values into an array and search the array. This will improve the performance.

Comment: Thanks for your response.But is it wise to store large data in array. Wont it crunch memory?.I will try to store data wisely and check.

Comment: You have to release the array once its not needed.